# How to sort page elements by z-index while debugging?

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio-2008

I'm debugging a JavaScript method on an ASP.NET 3.5 web site using jQuery in Visual Studio 2008. As a sanity check, I would like to look at a list of the page elements sorted by z-index. What's a good/easy way to do this? I would prefer an expression that I can input into the Watch window, but I'm open to other suggestions.

EDIT: @polarblau answered my question, but I wanted to post the code that I ended up using here where it's easier to read. Here's what I pasted into the Watch window in Visual Studio:

```
$.map($('*').sort(function(a, b) { return b.style.zIndex - a.style.zIndex; }), function(e) { return '[' + e.id + '] = [' + e.style.zIndex + ']'; }).join(', ')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would something like **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/Braxv/)** work? —

```
var sortByZIndex = function(a, b) {
    return a.style.zIndex - b.style.zIndex;
}
var sorted = $('div').sort(sortByZIndex);
alert("Sorted: " + $.map(sorted, function(e){ return e.id; }).join(', '));
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it would. I mashed it up into an ugly one liner and changed the sort order to descending, but it is essentially the same: $.map($('*').sort(function(a, b) { return b.style.zIndex - a.style.zIndex; }), function(e) { return '[' + e.id + '] = [' + e.style.zIndex + ']'; }).join(', ')